# Store variable in codeigniter object

Tags: codeigniter

Just one quick question . Please go through below code before i shoot the question.

```
class A extends CI_Controller{

    private $nam = null;
    private $nam1 = null;

    function __construct(){
      $this->nam="GOKUL";
      echo "IN CONST  ";
    }

    function index(){
      echo "ID:".$this->nam;
      $this->nam1="JADHAV";
   }

  function userdefined(){
   echo "UD:".$this->nam;
   echo "UD:name1:".$this->nam1;
  }

}//class
```

What i am trying to do is . I need to print JADHAV when userdefined function is called, but data is initialized in index function. How to achieve this .

This is sample code, but in my real time. I have huge data to load in array in index function and retrieve it in other function as u are seeing. I cannot use session / database to store . Is there any way ?

What i was also thinking is, how to store in the Codeigniter object and retrieve them. So that may be its available as global . Then may be i can reset.

Answer (score 0):

How and where do you intend to call userdefined()?

If you call it as a page (www.yoururl.com/a/userdefined - based on default CodeIgniter routing) there's no way you can read the property value if it's not stored in a DB or session or if it's not defined while executing the method.

You can call userdefined() from index() and load your index page (www.yoururl.com/a):

```
function index(){
      echo "ID:".$this->nam;
      $this->nam1="JADHAV";
      $this->userdefined(); //will print "UD: JADHAV"
}
```

Comment: Hi there. The project in which i am working the data come from xml . Its combination of many xmls. The decision to be made dynamically. So cant specify properly where. But i am looking for something like as i have explained earlier. Thank u so much for attempt.